# Filter / add_action to upgrade.php page

Tags: filters, wp-admin, upgrade

I'm wanting to change the wording and add some styling to the upgrade.php page.

We have a situation where we update our codebase across multiple sites via Git - when a user logs in after the update they are greeted with the "You must update your database" message.

This is fine but we want to refine the page a little, either filtering the text or adding a script to do it the dirty way.

The problem is I don't see any hook for this page and the text is hardcoded in upgrade.php.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [the first lines of that file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php), not counting comments/headers, are...

```
/** Include user install customize script. */
if ( file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/install.php') )
   require (WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/install.php');
```

You could include a custom install script with the rest of your code. That seems the most straightforward approach to me. It is hard to say a lot more as you haven't said what you want to do in much detail.

Comment: Hey s_ha_dum, thanks for that. Sorry for not being clear - I don't actually want to install anything, I just want to change the wording and add a stylesheet or script to that page. I want to change the way the 'Your database needs to be updated' message is displayed. Rob (sorry for the slow reply)

Comment: I understand that you aren't trying to install anything extra but this is a way to add content to that page, or by replacing the appropriate function which looks like the thing to do.

Comment: OK, thanks, just wanted to clarify. It took me a while to spot that include for some reason.. @s_ha_dum. Thanks, that's got it :) Happy Holidays ;)

Comment: If this solved the problem, please mark it "accepted". Look for the check mark on the side.

Comment: Done - thanks. Anything I echo out in /wp-content/install.php lands in the text box just as I need and styles get appended to the head, all good! Cheers.